# Why is my modal window not showing up?

Tags: html, bootstrap-modal

Here is my link to codepen:https://codepen.io/saisree/pen/XgKeyR

When i click on add button modal pop up is not coming up?
can someone please solve the issue?

```
 <a href="#" class="btn width100 FunctionBtn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#basicModal"><span class="BtnText">Add</span></a>

<div class="modal fade" id="basicModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="basicModal" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Basic Modal</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <h3>Modal Body</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you don't appear to have any js... at all. Have you considered reading **any** of the [documentation on bootstrap modal](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/modal/)?

Answer (score 0):

Forgot your files :) Include the bootstrap.js and also jquery. For CSS include bootstrap.css.

codepen.io/anon/pen/LLZmRY